Does google colab have a limit of how many images I can upload?
Similar (but doesn't help): PyTorch & Google Colab: ImageFolder doesn't load all images
I have downloaded an image dataset from kaggle. After that I uploaded the train (images) and labels (csv file)  data into a folder on google drive.
Using the "Mount Drive" option, I connected my google drive and succesfully imported the labels like this:
import pandas as pd
labels_df = pd.read_csv("drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/labels.csv")

The problem is that when I run these lines:
filenames = ["drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train/" + fname + ".jpg" for fname in labels_df["id"]]

import os
if len(os.listdir('drive/MyDrive/Dog Vision/train')) == len(filenames):
  print("Filenames match actual number of files!")
else:
  print("Filenames do not match actual number of files, check the data source!!")

In response, I get:
Filenames do not match actual number of files, check the data source!!

It seems that colab did not import the whole number of images. When I open the image folder and scroll down to the bottom, I see three dots:

In google drive, all images are intact. The full amount of images is 10222. Currently imported are only 4197:

